# Percentage of caps in a string

Tags: c#, string

Alright, so I'm trying to get the percentage of uppercase letters in a string. However, I'm not having much luck as my current code only says prints out if 100% of the string is uppercase.

```
int capsCount = 0;
foreach (char c in e.message)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(c))
        capsCount++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{(capsCount/e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length).ToString("0.00%")} is caps.");
Console.WriteLine($"{e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length}:{capsCount}");
```

Output from the console, #sydth is the irc channel, sydth is the username, and test is the message.

```
#sydth:sydth:TEST
100.00% is caps.
4:4

#sydth:sydth:test
0.00% is caps.
4:0

#sydth:sydth:teST
0.00% is caps.
4:2
```

Comment: My guess is the reason is because Length() and capsCount are both integers, so the result of division is integer as well. Convert them to floats before division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `capsCount` is `int` and never casted to `double/float/decimal`. And note that you divide it by `string.Length` which is also an `int`.

```
capsCount/e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length //both are int
```

Thus when you divide lower valued integer with higher value integer:

```
(int)9/(int)20 //illustration 9/20 -> 0.45 -> rounded down to 0
```

the result is rounded down and you will always get zero (and `e.message.Length` is always greater than `capsCount`)

The easiest solution would be to define it as `double` in the first place.

```
double capsCount; //declare as double
```

Alternatively, simply cast it double first before operation:

```
((double)capsCount/e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length).ToString("0.00%") //note that there is (double) there for casting
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast at least one of the properties in the division of the capsCount and the number of characters in the string to a decimal so it treats the division as decimal division rather than an integer division.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{((decimal)capsCount/e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length).ToString("0.00%")} is caps.");
```

Or you could make capsCount a decimal rather than an int;

```
decimal capsCount = 0;
foreach (char c in e.message)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(c))
        capsCount++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{(capsCount/e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length).ToString("0.00%")} is caps.");
Console.WriteLine($"{e.message.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length}:{capsCount}");
```